# In Extjs store Load adds multiple query values to the same query such as store.load({ Params: { status: 2 or 3 or 4} });

Tags: extjs

```
store.load({
  params: {
    start: 0,
    limit: SUGAR.dt.pagesize,
    'status': 2 or 3 or 4,
  }, callback: WIF.util.processcallback
});
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you did not specify a question in your description (just a code sample, also make sure to format your code).
Looking at the title: What do you mean by "query values". What is `2 or 3 or 4`? Do you want to define an array maybe?

Answer (score 0):

to check if status is 2,3 or 4 you need to check that in the response object.

to pass status of 2, 3 or 4 you need to pass ONE of these (or several as an array)